# Как подключить свой контейнер к алгоритму max_element?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, перегрузка-операторов

Я реализую свой контейнер. Мне нужно сделать его совместимым с алгоритмами из `algorithm`. Я решил начать с алгоритма `max_element`. Я в своем контейнере реализовал свой итератор, и передаю в `max_element` итератор начального элемента массива (мой контейнер реализован на динамическом массиве), а также конечный.

Но мне выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка    C2677   бинарный "!=": не найден глобальный оператор, принимающий
> тип "_FwdIt" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует).

Я так понимаю, что мне нужно перегрузить `!=`, но этот оператор у меня уже перегружен, поэтому я запутался.

Как исправить эту ошибку?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class MyContainer {
public:

    MyContainer(int size) {
        this->size = size;

        this->array = new T[this->size];

    }

    T& operator[](int index) {


        if (index >= this->size || index < 0) {

            cout << "Error, index was out of range!!!" << endl;

            return this->array[0];
        }


        return this->array[index];

    }

    class Iterator;

    Iterator begin() { return this->array; }
    Iterator end() { return this->array + this->size; }

    class Iterator
    {
    private:
        T* cur;
    public:
        Iterator(T *first) : cur(first)
        {}

        T& operator+ (int n) { return *(cur + n); }
        T& operator- (int n) { return *(cur - n); }

        T& operator++ (int) { return *cur++; }
        T& operator-- (int) { return *cur--; }

        T& operator++ () { return *++cur; }
        T& operator-- () { return *--cur; }

        bool operator!= (const Iterator& it) { return cur != it.cur; }
        bool operator== (const Iterator& it) { return cur == it.cur; }

        T& operator* () { return *cur; }

    };

    ~MyContainer() {
        delete[] this->array;
    }

private:
    int size;
    T* array;
};

int main() {

    int size = 5;

    MyContainer<int> Con(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Con[i] = i * 2;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    auto it1 = MyContainer<int>::Iterator(Con.begin());

    auto it2 = MyContainer<int>::Iterator(Con.end());

    auto result = max_element(it1, it2);

    cout << *result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У методов `==` `!=` должен быть `const` квалификатор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, а почему у вас инкремент/декремент возвращают `T&`?

```
Iterator& operator++ () { ++cur; return *this; }
Iterator& operator-- () { --cur; return *this; }
```

После чего все [будет работать](https://ideone.com/13H1lS).

Comment: Да, спасибо. Все заработало